# fit items to container's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 10 items in a container and each of them has margin from right hand side. With jquery, I am removing margin for every fifth item, but as the container's width is in percentage and item's width is in percentage as well, when I minimize or maximize my screen, items don't stretch to the end of container. How can I do it?

[`Here is the Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xg3qoe1x/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just give a percentage to the right margin.

The divs total width is 16% x 5 = 80% of the total width. So, the remaining width is 20%. Divide that by 5 (total div margins) and set to 4%:

```
margin-right:4%;
```

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xg3qoe1x/2/)

And also, you don't need jquery here to apply `margin-right: 0` to the fifth element. You can use css as shown below:

```
li:nth-child(5n){
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: yes I know about css nth-child selector, but I am trying to do for all browsers like IE8

Comment: @user3090189 just a suggestion: you can still do that in css like this: `li:first-child + li + li + li + li` (_which selects 5th element_).

Comment: Thanks Mr_Green for your suggestion.